# Cite Multiple sources Chicago manual style

Tags: citations, chicago-manual-of-style

I have cited the same source multiple times on one page of my essay. In my footnotes do I have to list the source each time, or is there a technique to list footnote numbers before the source like "1, 2, 3 2004 website about this" (Ignore the complete wrong naming of source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Chicago style, the following (from [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/717/)) may be considered:

> The first note for each source should include all relevant information
>   about the source: author’s full name, source title, and facts of
>   publication. If you cite the same source again, the note need only
>   include the surname of the author, a shortened form of the title (if
>   more than four words), and page number(s).
>
> If you cite the same source and page number(s) from a single source
>   two or more times consecutively, the corresponding note should use the
>   word “Ibid.,”  an abbreviated form of the Latin ibidem,  which means
>   “in the same place.” If you use the same source but a different page
>   number, the corresponding note should use “Ibid.” followed by a comma
>   and the new page number(s).

So, you would cite the sources in brief every time they come after the first full citation. To understand how to shorten the citation, refer [here](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/DocChicago_Notes_Shortened.html).